# All intent filters for music

Tags: android, android-intent

To get trak information from Android music apps I use those IntentFilter to start the receiver:

```
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
```

You know others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the filters I use:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");

    //HTC Music
    filter.addAction("com.htc.music.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.htc.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    //MIUI Player
    filter.addAction("com.miui.player.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.miui.player.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
    //Real
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    //SEMC Music Player
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_TRACK_STARTED");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_PAUSED");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.TRACK_COMPLETED");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playstatechanged");
    //rdio
    filter.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.rdio.android.playstatechanged");
    //Samsung Music Player
    filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playbackcomplete");
    filter.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    //Winamp
    filter.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    //Amazon
    filter.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.playstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
    //Rhapsody
    filter.addAction("com.rhapsody.playstatechanged");
    //PowerAmp
    filter.addAction("com.maxmpz.audioplayer.playstatechanged");
    //will be added any....
    //scrobblers detect for players (poweramp for example)
    //Last.fm
    filter.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    filter.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackpaused");
    filter.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackcomplete");
    //A simple last.fm scrobbler
    filter.addAction("com.adam.aslfms.notify.playstatechanged");
    // Others
    filter.addAction("net.jjc1138.android.scrobbler.action.MUSIC_STATUS");
    filter.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
```

**Edit:** I found [this](https://github.com/geecko86/QuickLyric/blob/master/QuickLyric/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) and [this](https://github.com/tgwizard/sls/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml). They could be useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType("uri-to-your-file", "audio/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```